# Django REST Framework - Reference to the User who added the order

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating an application in Django REST Fremework, in which the user can add an order. 
I would like the serializer to set a reference to the user based on the token and complete the "**Client**" model field.

It's actually works with HiddenField, as shown in the documentation.
(Link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield)

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    client = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = '__all__'
```

The problem is that when I fetch a single order or list of orders, **Client** field is of course hidden becouse of HiddenField type.

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/12
```

```
{
"id":12,
"name":"sprzatanie ogrodka",
"description":"dupa",
"price":"12.20",
"work_time_hours":2,
"work_time_minutes":50,
"workers_needed_num":3,
"coords_latitude":"-1.300000",
"coords_longitude":"1.100000",
"created_at":"2020-03-08T13:20:16.455289Z",
"finished_at":null,
"category":1,
"workers":[]
}
```

I would like the field to still capture reference to the logged in user, but at the same time to be visible when returning data from the API.

**What serializers field type I need to use?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the documentation i found: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

```
Using a standard field with read_only=True, but that also includes a default=… argument. This field will be used in the serializer output representation, but cannot be set directly by the user.
```

this is what you need i think. 
So whatever field type you have set in Model can be used with `read_only=True`
For example:

```
client = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

Hope this helps